# Null Pointer trying to bind a stringproperty

Tags: string, binding, javafx

I try to **bind** a `String` and a `StringPoperty`, I thought this would work :

```
@FXML private TextArea consoleTextArea;
StringProperty sp = new SimpleStringProperty();
consoleTextArea.textProperty().bind(sp);
```

But it return me a `NULL Pointer Exception`, Why ?

**EDIT** : After some answers it appears that my `consoleTextArea` is `NULL`, but I initialize it correctly : 
`<TextArea id="consoleTextArea" fx:id="consoleTextArea" prefHeight="309.0" prefWidth="600.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />` , and *I create the window before calling the controller*, so I don't undertand why is it `NULL` ...

Comment: Most likely the textarea is not initialized by the fxml loader. You might wonna double check, if the Name you used for the TextArea is correctly spelled within the FXML-File as well, or maybe you tried to bind the value, before the fxml loader is even called. But without the code, we can only guess whats really happening there.

Comment: It is indeed my consoleTextAea that seems null, but I load the FXML before ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is your `consoleTextArea` initialized? This is done by the FXML loader, so make sure you call it first before trying to use this field.
- Did you set the fx:id of the TextArea to `consoleTextArea` in Scene Builder?
- Does the TextArea contain any text?
- Try initializing sp with `new SimpleStringProperty("")`.

One of those should fix it.

Comment: TextArea does not contain any text, why is it important ?

Comment: I'm not sure it even matters (it shouldn't), but you never know, that's why I included it.

Comment: Well it was because my TextArea wasn't initialise ... Just add this point in you answer.

Comment: Alright :) I left that out because you said you called the FXML loader already.